# How to enable auto sharding in orientDB?

Tags: orientdb

Can anyone of you let me know how to enable auto-sharding feature in orientDB, after doing some search came to know that auto-sharding feature is supported in orientDB 2.0. (currently i am using 2.1.16 community version)

Comment: Have you already looked the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Distributed-Sharding.html ?

Comment: yes, i tried configuring the shards as mentioned in the documentation, but doing so orientdb is not creating shards as desired. @AlessandroRota